# data.table: How to drop grouping variable after aggregate/summarize

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I have a data.frame like below.  I want to summarize on `count` by the `element_id` and then drop the `element_id`.  I want to do this efficiently, but I can only achieve this by doing the summarizing and assigning to a variable and then dropping the column with `[,element_id:=NULL]`.

```
   element_id count
1           1     1
2           1     1
3           1     3
4           1     2
5           2     1
6           2     1
7           2     1
8           2     3
9           2     1
10          2     2
```

Here is the desired output:

```
   short poly
1:     3    1
2:     5    1
```

Here's my code:

```
library(data.table)

long_dat <- structure(list(
              element_id = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L,2L),
              count = c(1,1,3,2,1,1,1,3,1,2)),
              .Names = c("element_id","count"), row.names = c(NA,-10L), class = "data.frame")

data.table::setDT(long_dat)
data.table::setkey(long_dat, "element_id")
long_dat[, list(short = sum(count < 3), poly = sum(count > 2)), by=element_id]

# almost there
   element_id short poly
1:          1     3    1
2:          2     5    1

# an attempt to aggregate and drop at once but the aggregation does not occur
long_dat[, list(short = sum(count < 3), poly = sum(count > 2)), by=element_id][, element_id:=NULL]

# works but I assume the reassignment is inefficient
long_dat <- long_dat[, list(short = sum(count < 3), poly = sum(count > 2)), by=element_id]
long_dat[, element_id:=NULL]
```

Comment: Language tag ? :) Also, your attempt works but isn't save anywhere, e.g. `res <- long_dat[, list(short = sum(count < 3), poly = sum(count > 2)), by=element_id][, element_id:=NULL]`

Comment: Is the question whether there's another way than dropping with `[,gid:=NULL]`? The latter is almost costless, they say. You could alternately do `[,!"gid",with=FALSE]`

Comment: Can you both post as answers.  @DavidArenburg It works but why do I need to re-assign and then print?

Comment: @TylerRinker You can print by adding `[]` to the end of a data.table chain, too. I don't really get what the question is here, but I'll post an answer if you think I should.

Comment: You summarized the data and didn't assign it anywhere, so why should it be updated? When you used `:=`, you were already operating on the aggregated data, rather the original one. Also, `:=` suppresses print in v 1.9.5, and you need to call `print` twice after the `:=` assignment due to a bug that was present in previous versions see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/869)

Comment: Can any of you who answered via comments, just write an answer and OP please accept it? The bottom line is the code was ok, and `:=` is the recommended way, and the suppress-printing bug @DavidArenburg mentioned was fixed back in 10/2014, in data.table 1.9.6

Comment: @smci I didn't answer because I don't know what the question is. Tyler can self-answer if so inclined; or you could. Btw, I opened a request to omit the by= columns in the first DT[...] https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2061

Comment: @Frank: the question seems pretty clearly *"How to drop grouping variable the dt way after aggregate/summarize"*, I retitled it. And the answer is "Yes `dt[,, grouping_var:=NULL]` is the recommended way". OP was only unable to see that because of the old suppress-printing bug.